# I meet a something wrong about IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, json, listview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a Json data like ,I want to show the information in my listView so I parse them into a `ArrayList<String>` and then add to the adapter.

```
{
  "areas": [
    {
      "fieldTag": "1",
      "areaId": 2,
      "areaName": "No.1",
      "devices": [
        {
          "cameraName": "A",
          "busyFields": "null",
          "freeFields": "No.1,NO,2",
        },{
          "cameraName": "B"
          "busyFields": "null",
          "freeFields": "No.3,No.4",
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "error": 0,
  "message": "ok"
}
```

and I use Gson to parse it and I make the data to a list for show them in the Adapter,my code is :

```
if (mDeviceInfo.getError() == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i<mDeviceInfo.getAreas().size();i++){
                adapter.addSectionHeaderItem(mDeviceInfo.getAreas().get(i).getAreaName());
                for (int k = 0; k<mDeviceInfo.getAreas().get(i).getDevices().size();k++){

                    adapter.addItem(mDeviceInfo.getAreas().get(i).getDevices().get(k).getCameraName());

                    mPositionList.add(mDeviceInfo.getAreas().get(i).getDevices().get(k).getPosition());
                    mFreeFieldsList.add(mDeviceInfo.getAreas().get(i).getDevices().get(k).getFreeFields());
                    mBusyFieldsList.add(mDeviceInfo.getAreas().get(i).getDevices().get(k).getBusyFields());                 
      }
            }
            adapter.addMessage(mPosition,mFreeFields,mBusyFields);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"get info failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

and that is my code as the Adapter:

```
public class CameraListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> mPosition = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mFreeFields = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mBusyFields = new ArrayList<>();

    private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CameraListAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSectionHeaderItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        sectionHeader.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void addMessage(ArrayList<String> position,ArrayList<String> freeFields,ArrayList<String> busyFields){
        mPosition = position;
        mFreeFields = freeFields;
        mBusyFields = busyFields;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return sectionHeader.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SEPARATOR;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (rowType) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cameradetail, null);
                    viewHolder.mCameraName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cameraName);
                    Log.d("CameraListAdapter","position "+position);
                    viewHolder.mCameraName.setText(mData.get(position));

                    viewHolder.position = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cameraposition);
                    viewHolder.position.setText(mPosition.get(position));

                    viewHolder.busyFields = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.busyfields);
                    viewHolder.busyFields.setText(mBusyFields.get(position));

                    viewHolder.freeFields = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.freefields);
                    viewHolder.freeFields.setText(mFreeFields.get(position));

                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cameratag, null);
                    viewHolder.mTag = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.areaName);
                    viewHolder.mTag.setText(mData.get(position));
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTag;
        public TextView mCameraName;
        public TextView position;
        public TextView busyFields;
        public TextView freeFields;
    }


}
```

But it always show me that

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at .CameraListAdapter.getView(CameraListAdapter.java:106)
```

It upset me for 2 days so are there anyone to help me ?Thank you so much

Comment: What is line 106 of CameraListAdapter? Also extending ArrayAdapter might make more sense than BaseAdapter

Comment: The exception means you are trying to access an arraylist element using a `get(index)` with a non existing index (too large in your case). Some debug might help you figure out what's wrong

Comment: @cricket_007 which line? Do you mean the ViewHolder?

Comment: @RC. yeah,but I have try it again and again but I cannot find where the problem is. The Json data was post at the top

Comment: You spent 2 days and you don't know where the problem is? Read the logs.  `at .CameraListAdapter.getView(CameraListAdapter.java:106)`...  You are getting that exception on line 106.

Comment: @cricket_007 oh sorry , the line 106 is the `viewholder. position. setText()`

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}
```

you basically tell the adapter to call the `getView()` method for every item in you *mData* list. The position argument in your `getView()` method corresponds to the entry in your `mData` list. You then use that same position argument to get data out of three other lists that are probably of different size than the *mData* list so one of the `get(position)` calls on one of the other lists will throw the exception you are seeing. This can be easily debugged if you use the debugger in Android Studio on line 106 in your adapter.

Comment: So it means the override method `isEnable()` doesn't matter with the `position` which I used in `getView()` ?  I override isEnable method so the mTag was unable to click but does it mean it's position will still be existed

Comment: No, it means that you should not use the index of one `ArrayList` (in this case the *mData* list to get a item from another list. What if your *mData* list has a size of 10? the `getView()` method will be called with the *position* argument with value 10 and you use that position like this: `mFreefields.get(10)` when you don't even know what the length of the *mFreefields* list is.

Answer (score 0):

In an Adapter, the size of the data is determined by `getCount`, which you defined like so.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}
```

This means that the range of positions in `getView` is 0 to the value returned by `getCount`.

But, you seem to have 4 lists of various sizes, or at least not the same size as `mData`

```
private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> mPosition = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mFreeFields = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mBusyFields = new ArrayList<>();
```

I'm not sure which one is causing the problem, but, for example, this will throw an exception if `mPosition` doesn't hold the same amount of data as `mData`

```
viewHolder.position.setText(mPosition.get(position));
```

---

I would recommend you not have 4 separate String Arraylists since that data seems to pertain to a single Object, which if you want a proper custom Adapter, you give it a list of your Object type (parsed from Gson, for example) instead of individual pieces of an Object